# Extending Blade in Laravel - Creating a custom form object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The [documentation on extending blade in Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade) doesn't seem to have much depth and i'm struggling to understand if what I want to do is possible.

NOTE: I am using Laravel 5.1

This is the only example the Laravel Docs give for extending blade.

```
Blade::directive('datetime', function($expression) {
    return "<?php echo with{$expression}->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>";
});
```

Now what I want to do is have a blade file that looks like this:

```
@form('horizontal')
    {{ $form->text('email') }}
    {{ $form->text('password') }}
    {{ $form->submit }}
@endform
```

Then I want a new $form object to be created whenever I use @form and have it available to use after I use @form but it doesn't need to be available after @endform

After a bit of Googling and just messing around I have found I can do something like this:

```
\Blade::directive('form', function($expression) {
    return '<?php $form = new App\Form'.$expression.'; ?>
    <?php echo $form->open(); ?>';
});
```

(This was updated from a previous edit)

That's most of the way there. I have a $form object and can create a new form and I can send a custom param to that form object. I can also use the $form object after @form. Of course it will be available throughout the view, that's not perfect, but not necessarily a problem.

However since I seem to be doing something that is completely undocumented I fear I may be doing something wrong, or that I may run into problems later.

I should also note that every single guide I have found online refer to $compiler->createMatcher and $compiler->createPlainMatcher but both of these seem to be removed in Laravel 5.1.

Can anyone offer any insight into how blade extensions work and suggest better ways of doing this? Right now it seems to work just about, but feels very 'hacky' and perhaps not safe to rely on going forward.

## UPDATE HTML MACROS

To update on a use case for this based on an answer below suggesting HTML macros. CSS Framework Bootstrap includes different formatting for vertical and horizontal forms. The purpose of this functionality would be to make it easy to switch between these two, an example is below:

```
@form('horizontal')
    {{ $form->text("email", $user->email, 'Email') }}
@endform
```

The Form class might then look something like this:

```
class Form
{
    public $direction;

    public function __construct($direction)
    {
        $this->direction = $direction;
    }

    public function text($name, $value, $label)
    {
        return $this->wrap('<input type="text" value="'.$value.'" />', $name, $label);
    }

    public function wrap($element, $name, $label)
    {
        if($this->direction == 'horizontal') {
            //Horizontal
            return '<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="'.$name.'">'.$label.'</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    '.$element.'
                </div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            //Vertical
            return '<div class="form-group">
                <label for="'.$name.'">'.$label.'</label>
                '.$element.'
            </div>';
        }
    }
}
```

As far as i'm aware HTML Macro's cannot achieve this sort of thing.

This is all pseudo example code, so apologies for any errors. I believe the basic premise of it should be clear though.

Comment: You could extend the FormBuilder class and implement this functionality fairly easily without touching Blade. Take a look at `Form::model()` and how it saves the model's state. You could create your own opening method(s), or extend the existing methods with another parameter, and use it later on when individual methods are used.

Comment: @Cryode I haven't heard of the Form::model() method before so will look into how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into this plugin ["illuminate/html": "~5.0"](https://github.com/illuminate/html).

You can do things like open forms which these two method will do.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

{!! Form::model($pose,['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['poses.update', $pose->id]]) !!}
```

As a bonus you also get many other items.

```
{!! Form::text('title', null, [
           'class' => 'form-control', 
           'id' => 'title', 'placeholder' => 'Add title.'
          ]) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('body', null, [
           'class' => 'form-control', 
           'id' => 'body', 'placeholder' => 'Post a status'
          ]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And many others, [see the source](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php).

As far as your original question, you can always use the 5.0 function and just put the original method [`createOpenMatcher`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php) in your service provider. [See my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735429/laravel-5-1-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-view-compilers-bladecompiler/30743847#30743847)

```
public function createOpenMatcher($function){
    return '/(?<!\w)(\s*)@'.$function.'\(\s*(.*)\)/';
}
```

**Update per comment**

So per you comment, the Illuminate form helper will do what you are asking.

```
{{ Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}
```

Which renders as

```
<form method="POST" 
    action="http://example.com/sample" 
    accept-charset="UTF-8" 
    class="form-horizontal">
<input name="_token" 
    type="hidden" 
    value="ZqVwyZXXkh6sHLKpDJjvAJP0s6Bg5bXeuA1RcOnK">
```

Anything passed to the array is added to the form tag.

I might not understand your question 100%, but I think you may be trying to solve with Blade extensions something that might be much easier to solve with your code editor or the Form helper plugin. Maybe you could add the two types of HTML you are trying to generate and we could discuss that?

I use both [PhPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). Both of these have options where you can include code snippets of text. In PhPStorm they are called [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/live-templates.html) and Sublime calls them [snippets](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html).

I use a `textfield`<kbd>tab</kbd> live template for PhPStorm for my text fields.

```
<!-- $VALUE$ Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('$NAME$', '$VALUE$:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('$NAME$', null, [
               'class' => 'form-control', 
               'id'=>'$NAME$', 
               'placeholder' => '$VALUE$'
     ]) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('$NAME$', '<span class="error">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
```

Which gives you the render html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="sample">Sample:</label>
        <input class="form-control" 
               id="sample" 
               placeholder="Sample" 
               name="sample" 
               type="text">
 </div>
```

Although I do extend Blade from time to time. I have found that for the majority of times, when I want to extend it, there is usually an easier way.

## ***Final Edit***

Why don't you use CSS?

```
<style>
    form.horizontal .col-sm-10, form.horizontal .col-sm-2{
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>

<form class="horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field_name">Enter Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" value="New Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="vertical">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field_name">Enter Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" value="New Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see the update to my question. It doesn't help with this specific use case I am thinking of whereby I can modify each method based on what is sent to the __construct method of the Form class.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still think it missed the point somewhat. The example HTML is in the Form class in my question.

Comment: @robjbrain OK, so i think you are overthinking this. I updated my answer to use CSS. It seems as straight forward as you can get! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a Forms package that has been extracted out of the core framework. It is available here - http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

IMHO, extending Blade is not the best way to achieve what you want. You can use custom macros from the package above. E.g.,

```
Form::macro('horizontal', function()
{
    $form = '<input type="text" name="email">';
    $form .= '<input type="password" name="password">';
    $form .= '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
    return $form;
});
```

And in your view: `{!! Form::horizontal() !!}`

**Edit**: Response to updated question below

You can extend the `FormBuilder` class to add your own custom methods - https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.0/src/FormBuilder.php

Add a private `wrap` method that takes the input and direction. Or you could even have separate `wrapHorizontal` and `wrapVertical` methods.

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure if this quite achieves the same thing. The use case (in this instance) would be to utilise different mark up for Bootstrap horizontal and vertical forms. I will expand my question to reference this. If this can be done via macro's I would be impressed, but I don't think it can.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into extending the formBuilder class instead and update once i've tried some things

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link you may find it useful.
http://laravel-recipes.com/categories/21

Here the forms are of the form `{{ ..Code goes here.. }}`. In laravel 5.1 use these form syntax as `{!! ..Code goes here.. !!}`.